Using Revit converter functionality in 3dsmax design automation
I'm using 3dsmax batch locally to run the following Python script:
# Configure Revit Importer
rt.RevitImporterSetOption("viewdetail", 3)
rt.RevitImporterSetOption("extrudedetect", True)
rt.RevitImporterSetOption("simplifymesh", 0.25)
# etc...

rt.importFile(rvt_file_path, rt.Name('noPrompt'))

On my machine, I have the required versions of Revit and 3dsmax with the Revit Interoperability components installed, and this is working great.
I've deployed the script to Design Automation and tested with some work items, but the rt.importFile call always returns false when I check the Work Item report. The script runs fine otherwise, and I've confirmed the rvt file path is coming into the environment correctly.
It seems like the issue lies with the Revit importer itself just not running, and not throwing any errors. My only indication is that if I set the import result to a variable and log it, it always returns false.
Does anyone know if it's even possible to run the Revit import function in Design automation? And if not, I'm wondering if there's a way to package the required libraries in the App Bundle so that it loads properly in the 3dsmaxbatch environment.
Thank you!

Based on the talk with my colleague who are experienced in 3ds Mas Design Automation, Revit importer is not present in 3ds Max Design Automation 2024, so it won't work at the moment, it's a current known limitation. But this should work for 2023, could you please give a try with 3ds Max DA 2023?

Thanks for clarifying that, indeed I just tried 3dsmax DA 2023 and it runs the Revit importer as expected. Are there plans to add the Revit importer to 3dsmax DA 2024?

Yes, it's in our radar, but not ready yet.

Thanks. I see that 3dsmax 2025 is an available engine in DA now, is there a rough ETA on support for the Revit importer in 2024/25?

Unfortunately, it's still not available on the latest engine as I was told today. Sorry for that, and i don't have an ETA for that at this moment.
